# Facebook saying page is not liked when I go to my index in canvas

Tags: php, facebook

The page is liked and my app is checking if its liked but if I go back to the index.php it say s it isn't liked.

I was using:

```
if ($signed['page']['liked'] <> 1) {
    $core->redirect('gate');
}
```

Then I started using this, but when I click index it moves all the way to apps.facebook.com/myapp and then redirects back to the other page. But the issue is have another index.php file in adifferent folder for a different language which I cant use since it'll redirect to the english version. How can I fix this?

```
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;

}
  if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {
      //echo "This content is for Fans only!";
    } else {
      //echo "Please click on the Like button to view this tab!";
      $core->redirect('gate');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `page` section in the `signed_request` is only present when the app is loaded in a page tab, not as a canvas app.

{edit based on comment below: - read the [`signed_request` documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) - the signed request is present only on the POST request made from Facebook - it's not present if the user clicks through to links inside the page tab app, or if you redirect from the landing URL to another URL inside your app}

Comment: I dont understand it works if I refresh the page but when I go to lets say x.php and then want to go back to index.php it doesnt work

Comment: By why wouldl it get lost when I go back to the original pages (ex http://www.y.com/index.php as opposed to when i go to http://www.y.com/em.php )

Comment: The signed_request is only passed to your app when its initially loaded into the iframe – once you navigate around in your app, that parameter is not available any more. (And of course, it gets POSTed again if you reload the whole Facebook page.) So if you need the info on subsequent pages, store it somewhere, f.e. in the session, so that you can access it on the following pages as well.

Comment: Yep, this was the gist of my edit - you can't move users around inside the iframe and keep the signed request, it's only sent on the initial load